# There are finitely many critical points for a non-degenerate action.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a compact symplectic manifold, and $J$ be a compatible almost complex structure. Given a $1$-periodic Hamiltonian $H: M \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, we define the *action functional* $A_H: \Omega_0(M) \to \mathbb{R}$ (here $\Omega_0(M)$ is the space of contractible loops) by
$$A_H(x)=\int_D u^*\omega+\int_0^1H(x(t),t)dt,$$
where $u$ is a capping disk for $x$ (we put an asphericity condition so that this is well-defined). One can prove that the critical points correspond to solutions of $\dot{x}(t)=X_t(x(t))$ (where $X_t$ is the Hamiltonian vector field), and that the flow of $-\nabla A_h$ is given by solutions of the Floer equation (disregarding the fact that the flow may not be globally defined etc).

A *non-degenerate* critical point is a path $x$ which is a critical point and such that the linearized flow has no eigenvalue $1$.
The book by Audin, Damian claims that if all critical points are non-degenerate, then there are finitely many, but I don't understand why that is true. The question then is: Why nondegeneracy in this case implies finitely many critical points?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a matter of fact, this has nothing to do with symplectic structures. The relevant fact is the following.

**Lemma:** Let $M$ be a *compact* smooth manifold, and let $\varphi:M\to M$ be a diffeomorphism whose fixed points are all non-degenerate. Then $\varphi$ has finitely many fixed points.

This lemma follows from the fact that a non-degenerate fixed point has to be isolated.

I think that the claim in your post does not necessarily hold when omitting the compactness assumption.

Comment: $M$ is assumed to be compact in the post, sorry for not making this explicit.

However, I don't see how this result is related. Here our critical points are in fact loops, and the definition of "non-degenerate" is (a priori) unrelated to the finite dimensional counterpart (note that I define what non-degenerate means). Can you elaborate how to reconcile?

Comment: Furthermore, proving that a fixed point is isolated is also a delicate matter, since one must be careful about what topology to take on $\Omega_0(M)$ etc. The point I'm trying to make is the following: the analysis is not directly a corollary of the standard finite-dimensional case.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo The diffeomorphism $\varphi$ is the $1$-Hamiltonian flow. You are looking for fixed points of this. And being non-degenerate means that the graph of $\varphi$ intersects the diagonal in $M\times M$ transversally. It then follows that a non-degenerate fixed point is isolated.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo And just to be clear, I'm not thinking about the (infinite-dimensional) loop space. I'm think of maps $M\to M$.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo By the way, this whole Floer business came to life to address the Arnold conjecture, which concerns fixed points of Hamiltonian diffeomorphisms. Studying gradient flows in the loop space has been proven to be very useful, but still, it is only a tool in this context. The critical points in the loop space are exactly fixed points of the Hamiltonian flow, and as explained in my answer, the proof you are looking for only uses properties of non-degenerate fixed points of diffeomorphisms.